# How do I handle client side routes, when a page refresh returns the backend rails' route instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, routes, deployment

I have deployed my SPA to Render. It consists of a React with Redux frontend, and a Rails backend. When the app mounts, it renders the correct frontend route in the browser, and any subsequent navigation without refreshing the page works. However, when I refresh the page, or navigate directly to a URL like https://trakable.onrender.com/projects, the browser returns the JSON data from the server instead of the frontend Projects component.

I have another deployed app set up in a very similar fashion that does not have this problem. I have a fallback controller for rendering the index.html file which looks like this:

```
class FallbackController < ActionController::Base

  def index
    # React app index page
    render file: 'public/index.html'
  end
end
```

and I've included some routing logic in my routes.rb file like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
      get '/me', to: 'users#show'
      post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
      delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
      resources :teams
      resources :users, only: [:index]
      resources :tasks
      resources :projects

  # Routing logic: fallback requests for React Router.
  # Leave this here to help deploy your app later!
  get "*path", to: "fallback#index", constraints: ->(req) { !req.xhr? && req.format.html? }
end
```

I have a proxy setup for http://localhost:3000 in package.json so that the routes in my slices can look like this:

```
export const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk("users/fetchUsers", () => {
    return fetch("/users")
    .then((r) =>r.json())
})
```

My database.yml file has production set like so:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

My app component looks like this:

```
import './styles/App.css';
import NavBar from './navbar/NavBar'
import Tasks from './tasks/Tasks'
import LoginPage from './users/LoginPage'
import Task from './tasks/Task'
import EditTask from './tasks/EditTask'
import Projects from './projects/Projects'
import Project from './projects/Project'
import Teams from './teams/Teams'
import Team from './teams/Team'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { fetchCurrentUser, fetchUsers } from './users/usersSlice'
import { fetchProjects } from './projects/projectsSlice'
import { fetchTeams } from './teams/teamsSlice'

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.users.currentUser);
  console.log(currentUser);

  // Initialize previousUserId to null
  const [previousUserId, setPreviousUserId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCurrentUser())
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the user has changed (new user login)
    if (currentUser && currentUser.id !== previousUserId) {
      // Dispatch fetch actions when a new user logs in
      dispatch(fetchUsers());
      dispatch(fetchProjects());
      dispatch(fetchTeams());

      // Update previousUserId to the current user's ID
      setPreviousUserId(currentUser.id);
    }
  }, [dispatch, currentUser, previousUserId]);

  if (loading) {
    return <div></div>
  }

  if (!currentUser || currentUser.errors) {
    return <LoginPage />
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route
          path="/"
          element={<Tasks />}/>
          <Route 
          path="/tasks/:id"
          element={<Task />}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/tasks/:id/edit"
          element={<EditTask />}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/projects"
          element={<Projects />}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/projects/:id"
          element={<Project />}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/teams"
          element={<Teams />}
          />
          <Route 
          path="/teams/:id"
          element={<Team />}
          />
        </Routes>
    </main>

  );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried adding namespacing and/or scope with my backend routes, but wasn't successful. It appeared to prevent the browser from returning JSON instead of frontend components, but it altered my routes in such a way as to break things. For example, by submitting a form to update a Task on a page like https://trakable.onrender.com/tasks/3/edit, the request was sent to a url like https://trakable.onrender.com/tasks/3/api/tasks/3, instead of just tasks/3.

Comment: Ok so I think it has to do with the fact that some of my backend routes and frontend routes have the same path, so a page refresh makes a GET request to that path, which is why it's returning the JSON, and not the component.

Comment: Ok I think that was it. Changing my frontend routes from something like /projects to /users/:id/projects seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: if you've resolved the issue, you should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This app is running React within Rails, so Rails will be responsible for handling all of the routing logic for the application. When a request comes through that isn't a request for an API route (ie a client-side route), we need to have a fallback route that will render the index.html file.

Ensure you've created a fallback_controller:

```rb
class FallbackController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    # React app index page
    render file: 'public/index.html'
  end
end
```

Then, in config/routes.rb, include this line as the first route:

`get "*path", to: "fallback#index", constraints: ->(req) { !req.xhr? && req.format.html? }`

It's important that the fallback route be first in routes.rb. If not, API routes can be returned instead of the index.html file.